# Android Studio - How to show parameters of functions?

Tags: android-studio

In almost any IDE one can re-open the suggestion list for parameters of the function your cursor is currently at. `CTRL + SPACE` usually did the trick. But all I'm getting is useless list of I don't know what:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `getPadding()` accepts integer arguments it might be useful to show you the list of all methods which return integer value / integer constants. And this is exactly what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> does.
If you want to see the method parameter information, you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>; if you want to see full function declaration, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.